# Will I be okay if I use USB-stick with 1.87 GB of free space to install Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, usb

I want to install Ubuntu 12.10 from a USB-stick, but there's only 1.87GB of free space.

Will there be any problems with it or is it okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to make usb bootable and installing ubuntu it will work because ubuntu will be around 700 mb. But if you need to install in it you can't

Comment: 700 MB is about the size of three regular photos. How can Ubuntu fit into that?

Comment: Note that creating a bootable USB will delete your files on it.

Comment: @nerof61: 700 MB is quite a lot more than 3 large photos. Most digital camera's (even when set to max resolution) will produce pictures with a size of about 5 MB. ( or 140 photos in 700 MB ).

Comment: its the size of ubuntu installation file. When you make a bootable USB to boot and install ubuntu it require only around 700. But it you PC or Laptop your require 5 GB minimum

Comment: I guess so. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in here: [Ubunut 12.10 System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

**Recommended Minimum System Requirements**
The Recommended Minimum System Requirements, here, should allow even someone fairly new to installing Ubuntu or Gnu&Linux to easily install a usable system with enough room to be comfortable. A good "rule of thumb" is that machines that could run XP, Vista, Windows 7 or x86 OS X will almost always be a lot faster with Ubuntu even if they are lower-spec than described below. Simply try Ubuntu CD as a LiveCD first to check the hardware works.

**Ubuntu Desktop Edition**

700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)

512 MiB RAM (system memory)

5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)

VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution

Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media

Internet access is helpful

**Ubuntu Server (CLI) Installation**

300 MHz x86 processor

128 MiB of system memory (RAM) (256 MiB for a virtual installation)

1 GB of disk space

Graphics card and monitor capable of 640x480

CD drive

as you see you need more space, but you can use it in live/persistent mode, search in google to find many article on this.